# can i use onblur on a select list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, select, onblur

> when i choose another option than the first in a select list i want the asterisk to be removed!

```
<script>
function opchk() {
  if (document.getElementById("ops").value = 'Select size') { 
    document.getElementById(asterisk9).style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(asterisk9).style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

> where is my mistake?

```
<div class="type1" id="top4">
  <h>Size:</h>
  <h class="astyle" id="asterisk9">*</h>
</div>

<select style="width:90px" id="ops" onblur="opchk()">
  <option value="op1">Select size</option>
  <option value="op2">5</option>
  <option value="op3">10</option>
  <option value="op4">15</option>
  <option value="op5">20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please try to indent your code, its a good practice and  makes easier to read and review your code

Comment: `document.getElementById("ops").value = 'Select size'` <-- your problem

Comment: Your function does not have a closing bracket.

Comment: Also please add quotes for your selector `document.getElementById(asterisk9)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is littered with errors and no one solution would fix them all.

Comment: people!! this place is for learning, my code shouldnt be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few errors throughout. Getting started with javascript can be a little daunting, but using console.log() can be really helpful to see how far the code is getting before it breaks, or find out if something is returning a value you don't expect. Good luck!

```js
function opchk() {
  if (document.getElementById("ops").value == "op1") { //in the select list, you set the values to op1, op2, etc. So that's what you should be using for comparison. Also you need to use == or === to compare values, = is used to set the value of things.
    document.getElementById("asterisk9").style.visibility = "visible"; //this is situational, but using "visibility" rather than "display" will prevent things from shifting around since the element is still there just hidden/visible.
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("asterisk9").style.visibility = "hidden"; //the id "asterisk9" should be in quotes when selecting it with document.getElementById()
  }
} //missing closing bracket of opck()
```

```html
<div class="type1" id="top4">
  <h>Size:</h>
  <h class="astyle" id="asterisk9">*</h>
</div>

<select style="width:90px" id="ops" onchange="opchk()"><!--I would also use onchange in this case to make it feel more responsive.-->
  <option value="op1">Select size</option>
  <option value="op2">5</option>
  <option value="op3">10</option>
  <option value="op4">15</option>
  <option value="op5">20</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

So your two biggest issues are a missing bracket on the `opchk` function and using a single `=` over `==` or `===`.

`=` is assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left
`==` is checking for equality loosely (1 is equal to 1 as well as "1")
`===` is checking for strict equality (1 is equal to 1 but not "1")

```
<script>
function opchk() {
  if (document.getElementById("ops").value === 'Select size') { 
    document.getElementById("asterisk9").style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("asterisk9").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>


<div class="type1" id="top4">
  <h>Size:</h>
  <h class="astyle" id="asterisk9">*</h>
</div>

<select style="width:90px" id="ops" onblur="opchk()">
  <option value="op1">Select size</option>
  <option value="op2">5</option>
  <option value="op3">10</option>
  <option value="op4">15</option>
  <option value="op5">20</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to compare inside an if statement, you have to use **==** instead of **=**. 
also don't forget to add a closing bracket for your function.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome hannon qaoud!

You have a couple of syntax errors in your code.

```js
function opchk() {
  // if (document.getElementById("ops").value = 'Select size') { // <- error here, one = means you are setting a value
  if (document.getElementById("ops").value == 'Select size') { // should be == or ===

    // document.getElementById(asterisk9).style.display = "block"; <- error here, asterisk9 is already element reference
    
    // will work like this
    document.getElementById('asterisk9').style.display = "block"; // reselect by id
    // or 
    asterisk9.style.display = "block"; // using asterisk9 as element reference
  }
  else {
    // same here
    document.getElementById('asterisk9').style.display = "none";
    // or 
    asterisk9.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="type1" id="top4">
  <h>Size:</h>
  <h class="astyle" id="asterisk9">*</h>
</div>

<select style="width:90px" id="ops" onblur="opchk()">
<option value="op1">Select size</option>
<option value="op2">5</option>
<option value="op3">10</option>
<option value="op4">15</option>
<option value="op5">20</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to just change one line then it should work

```
if (document.getElementById("ops").value == 'Select size') {
// Change this to like:
if (document.getElementById("ops").value == 'op1') {
```

It should work.